# Is the inf-convolution of two continuous functions continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

For two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ defined on a normed space $E$ taking values in $[-\infty,\infty)$, let 
$f\square g: x\mapsto \inf\{f(y)+g(x-y): y \in E\}$. Here I do not assume any properties of $f$ and $g$ other than continuity.

Is the function $f\square g$ necessarily continuous?

I am particularly interested in the case where $E$ is the set of bounded measurable functions on some measurable space (i.e. bounded random variables).

I know two facts:

1) if one of $f$ and $g$ is upper-semicontinuous then so is $f\square g$.

2) if one of $f$ and $g$ is uniformly continuous then so is $f\square g$.

However for continuity it seems very different and I could not find a counter-example.

Comment: I figured this out myself. The answer is that $f\square g$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Perhaps you could add your proof as an answer below, for the benefit of the community? :)

Comment: For a counter-example, it suffices to take $E=\mathbb R$.  Let $f(x)= x^2=-g(x)$, $x\in \mathbb R$.
Clearly, both $f$ and $g$ are continuous. We can calculate
$$
f\square g(0) = \inf\{f(y)+g (-y): y\in \mathbb R\}  = 0,
$$
and for $\epsilon\ne 0$,
\begin{align*}
f\square g(\epsilon)  = \inf \{ (y+\epsilon)^2 - y^2 : y\in \mathbb R  \}
=  \inf \{  2y\epsilon + \epsilon^2  : y\in \mathbb R  \}   = -\infty.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f\square g$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Sorry about the typo; it should be $f(y) + g(x-y)$, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Infimal_convolution.  
Let me modify the question.